# Omitting rows from query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to query a sheet in google docs. The issue I'm having is that I only want the query to return a list of companies that are either "Customer" or "Referrals". The Customer and Referrals  text are in a dropdown menu in a column named "Status" in a tab/sheet named "Contacts". The issue I'm running into is that when the query gets to a row where the value is NOT "Customer" or "Referrals" it automatically populates it with the last known customer. I've tried making changes and in the best case scenario it leaves the rows blank that aren't = "Customer" or "Referrals". What I'm TRYING to acheive is having those rows skipped so there aren't a bunch of blank rows (or a bunch of rows of the same customer) between Customers.

***WHAT I'M GETTING:***

```
|Vee Zee Home Services|   
|Scott Norris         |        
|Maple Hill           |      
|Maple Hill           |                   
|Maple Hill           |                   
|Maple Hill           |                   
|Maple Hill           |                   
|Wright Construction  |             
|Jenema Builders      |                  
|Jenema Builders      |  
|Jenema Builders      |  
|Jenema Builders      |  
|Costanza Homes       |               
|A. Rink Architects   |
```

***WHAT I WANT:***

```
|Vee Zee Home Services|  
|Scott Norris         |  
|Maple Hill           |  
|Wright Construction  |  
|Costanza Homes       |  
|A. Rink Architects   |
```

- Here's the query I'm using:

---

```
=QUERY(Contacts!A1:F15,"SELECT A WHERE ((lower(C) = 'customer') OR (lower(C) = 'referrals')) AND ((lower(C) != 'investigage') AND (lower(C) != 'lost') AND (lower(C) != 'bidding') AND (lower(C) != 'suspect') AND (lower(C) != 'prospect') AND (lower(C) != 'contact') AND (lower(C) != 'abandoned')) limit 1", false)
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see how to [ask] and edit your question. Also please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Contacts!A1:F15, 
 "select A 
  where lower(C) matches 'customer|referrals' 
  limit 1", 0)
```

---

### update:

cell `B2`:

```
=QUERY(Contacts!A1:F,
 "select A,B where lower(C) matches 'customer|referrals' and A is not null", 0)
```

cell `I2`:

```
=QUERY(Contacts!A1:F,
 "select C where lower(C) matches 'customer|referrals' and A is not null", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! However it’s producing the same results. It’s still responding by auto populating the rows that should be omitted with the last true result. The same as what I was getting before. Thank you so much for your help I’m a noob so I really appreciate your patience. 

-Nate

Comment: @NateHoule can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: absolutely! here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B23VqtP8tE25iH3ZOyKkCmUXzmEOqjcfkdb6GKfjr-c/edit?usp=sharing I've created a tab called "desired output" to pull from contacts.

Comment: @NateHoule answer updated